# Url status using jxbrowser

Tags: url, http-status-codes, jxbrowser

I 'am using jxbrowser ,

How to get **url status code** such as (200 or 400 or redirect)

I tried this   [jxbrowser_events_status](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013724-status-events)
but it didn't give me what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain url status code using the [NetworkDelegate.onHeadersReceived()](https://www.teamdev.com/downloads/jxbrowser/javadoc/com/teamdev/jxbrowser/chromium/NetworkDelegate.html#onHeadersReceived-com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.HeadersReceivedParams-) callback:

```
Browser browser = new Browser();
NetworkService networkService = browser.getContext().getNetworkService();
networkService.setNetworkDelegate(new DefaultNetworkDelegate() {
    @Override
    public void onHeadersReceived(HeadersReceivedParams params) {
        int statusCode = params.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    }
});
```